# How do I make a button show different inputs from different lists?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app, and I have a timer functionality. The timer has a timer, obviously, and a container where it displays a scramble. I've made that container stateful, so that when you tap it it gives you the next scramble. But right now it only displays scrambles from one List. How can I make it display different scrambles from different lists, based on what option the user has picked? In my example, I have a button, and if the user clicks name #1, I want that container to change to show scrambles for name #2. If the user picks name #2, I want the container to show only name #2 scrambles, and so forth. How do I do this? Here is the code for the timer screen:

```
class TestTimer extends StatefulWidget {
const TestTimer({super.key});

@override
State<TestTimer> createState() => _TestTimerState();
}

class _TestTimerState extends State<TestTimer> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    child: Center(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text("F R U R' U' F'"), //Ignore this GestureDetector chunk.
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}

 class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 const ParentWidget({super.key});

 @override
  State<ParentWidget> createState() => ParentWidgetState();
}

class ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
 int counter = 0;
 List scrambles = [
   "F R U R' U' F'",
   "R F' R2 F2 D' L2 U2 L2 D U2 F2 U' R2 F R'",
   "L U F' L2 B D L' F' D' F2 L2 B'", //This is my List with scrambles.
];
 void incrementCounter() {
setState(() {
  counter++;
});
 }

  bool active = false;

  void _handleTapboxChanged(bool newValue) {
   setState(() {
    active = newValue;
    });
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SizedBox(
  child: TapboxB(
    active: active,
    onChanged: _handleTapboxChanged,
    scrambles: scrambles,
    counter: counter,
    incrementCounter: incrementCounter,
  ),
);
 }
 }

class TapboxB extends StatelessWidget {
 final void Function() incrementCounter;
 final bool active;
 final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
 final List scrambles;
 final int counter; 


 const TapboxB({
super.key,
this.active = false,
required this.incrementCounter,
required this.onChanged,
required this.scrambles, 
required this.counter, 
});

  void _handleTap() {
  onChanged(!active);
  }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
  onTap: _handleTap,
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: null),
    child: Center(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          incrementCounter();
        },
        child: Text(
          '${scrambles[counter % scrambles.length]}',
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
       ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
 }
```

The 'button' that the user will click to select name #1 or name #2 is in another screen and file, so here it is:

```
class TwoTimerAlgsets extends StatefulWidget {
const TwoTimerAlgsets({super.key});

 @override
  State<TwoTimerAlgsets> createState() => TwoTimerAlgsetsState();
 }

class TwoTimerAlgsetsState extends State<TwoTimerAlgsets> {
int counter2 = 0;
 List scrambles2 = ['Coal, Present'];

 void incrementCounter2() {
  setState(() {
    counter2++;
});
 }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('2x2 Algsets'),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          incrementCounter2;
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 50.0,
            color: Colors.white24,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                'name #1',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
          color: Colors.white24,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'name #2',
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
 }
}
```

I've tried making different Lists and such, but I can't figure it out. Help is appreciated!

Comment: You can add a different GestureRecognition for each Text and then call the method that woould bring the scrambles based on and index paramater. I.e.   `OnTap( getScrambles("1") , child: Text("Name #1")))    On Tap( getScrambles("2"), child Text("Name #2")))`